# Flutter Localization with ARB files

Tags: flutter, dart, arb

Actually I was using Arb files for localization in that I don't know how to make and access array type value in .arb files with flutter

Comment: you can find full details about it in here, https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization
also install the `intl` plugin in android studio, which will handle all the automated code generation process

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply define your object as a String separated by some common separator:

```
  "months": "january:february:march:april:may:june:july:august:september:october:november:december",
  "@months": {
    "description": "months"
  },
```

Then, split the String into an array:

```
String monthsString = AppLocalizations.of(context)!.months;
List<String> months = monthsString.split(':');
```